# Can someone guide me with correct way to iterate in the following code

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

This is a question from Python Challenge: Double letters

> The goal of this challenge is to analyze a string to check if it
> contains two of the same letter in a row. For example, the string
> "hello" has l twice in a row, while the string "nono" does not have
> two identical letters in a row.
>
> Define a function named double_letters that takes a single parameter.
> The parameter is a string. Your function must return True if there are
> two identical letters in a row in the string, and False otherwise.

I tried below code:

```py
def double_letters(word):
    for i in range(len(word)+1):
        if word[i] == word[i+1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

double_letters('hello')
```

The problem here is : when i return false at the end of my function, it works perfectly fine for a true statement (e.g. 'Hello'), but doesn't work for False statement (e.g. 'Master'), i get an error instead: IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: What went wrong? Also, why are you adding one: `len(word) + 1` ?

Comment: You should step through the loop inside of your head. It goes through the loop, first i=0. It checks word[0]==word[1], that is False. So it executes the 'else' statement. Which, returns false. But you want to keep looping? So remove the 'else' clause and at the end of your function return false.

Comment: It doesn't work for the false statement that way.. I am a bit confused about looping..

Comment: The loop is fine, when you write 'return False' you stop the loop immediately. You need to remove the 'else'. The logic is like this, if you find a double letter return true immediately. If you don't keep looking.

Comment: understood your point. But the problem here is : when i return false at the end of my function, it works perfectly fine for a true statement (e.g. 'Hello'), but doesn't work for False statement (e.g. 'Master'), i get an error instead: IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: I found out the other mistake what I was doing here.. Instead of using (len(word)+1), i should have used (len(word)-1), since my if statement was using the index as index+1..

Answer (score 2):

I was using a wrong range for the 'for loop'. Since, my if statement uses index+1, so my code was throwing an error as out of range..
Below is the correct code:

```
def double_letters(word):
    for i in range(len(word)-1):
        if word[i] == word[i+1]:
            return True
    return False     
double_letters('hello')
```

Comment: I added your comment to the question. Since it makes a better question to explain what the problem is. It's good to se you figured it out!